# biblatex apa style no showing page numbers for inproceedings

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am running biblatex + biber. When the bibliography is printed in APA style, @inproceeding entries do not have any page numbers attached. This does not happen for other styles such as MLA.

Here is the output:

[image]

Here is my minimum working example:

**sample.tex**

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=apa,
backref=false,
sortcites=true,
sorting=nyt,
citestyle=authoryear,
mincitenames=1,
maxcitenames=2
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello}
\label{sec:hello}

\parencite{test}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**sample.bib**

```
@inproceedings{test,
  author = {Test Author},
  title = {Test title},
  pages = {108--115},
  booktitle = {Test Conference Proceedings},
  year = 2016,
}
```

And here are the results of \listfiles:

```
 *File List*
  report.cls    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
biblatex.sty    2019/12/01 v3.14 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)
pdftexcmds.sty    2019/11/24 v0.31 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
   iftex.sty    2019/11/07 v1.0c TeX engine tests
 ltxcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
etoolbox.sty    2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
kvoptions.sty    2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def    2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
     apa.dbx    2020/02/01 v9.5 APA biblatex style data model
blx-compat.def    2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
biblatex.def    2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
standard.bbx    2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
     apa.bbx    2020/02/01 v9.5 APA biblatex references style
authoryear.cbx    2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex citation style (PK/MW)
biblatex.cfg    
   babel.sty    2020/02/14 3.40 The Babel package
 british.ldf    2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
l3backend-pdfmode.def    2020-02-03 L3 backend support: PDF mode
 british.lbx    2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
 english.lbx    2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
american.lbx    2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
american-apa.lbx    2020/02/01 v9.5 APA biblatex localisation
english-apa.lbx    2020/02/01 v9.5 APA biblatex localisation
british-apa.lbx    2020/02/01 v9.5 APA biblatex localisation
  sample.bbl
 ***********
```

Comment: If you want real APA style (`style=apa,`), remove the options `sorting=nyt, citestyle=authoryear, mincitenames=1, maxcitenames=2`. `style=apa,` automatically sets all the required options to the correct values.

Comment: @moewe Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MWE uses MLA, not APA. After I changed it, page numbers are displayed as expected. However, I'm using biblatex-apa v9.14 and you are using v9.5. Try updating the package.

Comment: Oops, that's just an artifact of me testing. I have edited.

Comment: I will attempt to update to 9.14, thanks!

Comment: This was the issue -- thanks very much!